# Pubsub: Mark as read

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I am using Pub sub to implement a notification system similar to Facebook notifications with ejabberd on the server side and strophe on the client side.

Now, in the implementation how can I do a “Mark as read” so that the server does not push any items that have been read/notified?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a custom Publish and Subscribe module for ejabberd for that feature. This feature is outside of the XMPP PubSub specification.